# Why does my Excel table multiply columns when I insert/delete rows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This Excel program have a table which have some columns which collects data from several master tables.

Using the code like so:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

'Autofill Die Description after Die No is filled
'If Project No is not empty then do the following
If Not Intersect(target, Me.ListObjects("F.Main").ListColumns("Project No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

 With target.Offset(0, 1) '1 column to the right of Project No
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(D.Entry,MATCH(rc[-1],D.Entry[Project No],0),2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
 
 With target.Offset(0, 2)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(D.Entry,MATCH(rc[-2],D.Entry[Project No],0),3),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
 
 With target.Offset(0, 3)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(D.Entry,MATCH(rc[-3],D.Entry[Project No],0),4),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

.

.

.

End If
```

When I try to insert or delete new rows in that table this happens:

[image]

What is causing this?

Comment: Since there is a code in worksheet_change module it probably has something to do with that. Meaning everytime you make changes to the worksheet, such as deleting a row, the macro fires.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following solution:

I define a global var in a module named `Main`

```
Public EnableEvents As Boolean
```

In the initialization phase I set it to `True`. Then in the `Worksheet_change` routine

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

If Main.EnableEvents Then 
   Main.EnableEvents = False

   If Not Intersect ...   copy your actual code here

   Main.EnableEvents = True
Endif

End Sub
```

Comment: But doing that will disable the autofill columns.

Comment: Make sure the `Main.EnableEvents = True` before the worksheet_change routine fires the first time.